# Hosting .NET Core API + Web Site on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core

What are the best practices for how this is setup? The solution has two .NET Core apps, one for the services layer and the second for the web UI (single page design). Are they just setup as individual sites in IIS? Or is it setup like a master site (UI) with a child site underneath for the services?

What are best practices for how the URLs look?

Comment: Assuming you have created your project with File/New Solution, then it should do everything required to configure IIS automatically.   Basically, IIS knows about the web UI project.

Comment: Flagged this as off topic because the answer would always be subjective. There are tons of resources available on this topic.

Comment: @aevitas - then why not share a link or two? I must not be searching the right thing because I've yet to find a microsoft article or blog that covers this. ASP.NET Core app on it's own, sure. .NET Core API app on it's own, sure. But putting it all together and how it winds up hosted on IIS etc I've not been able to find

Comment: @snappymcsnap you Deploy the app then you deploy the api  as separate websites, but you can have them under the same domain i.e. `http://app.com` and `http://api.app.com`. but ultimately they are separate apps; domain configuration is up to you.

Comment: @AntonToshik OK so basically treat them as though they were completely unrelated sites as far as IIS is concerned, thank you for your reply.

Comment: @AntonToshik is correct. It makes it simpler for future as well since you can have multiple web apps accessing same service layer from different locations. E.g. API1 can be published to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apis\api1`, .NET Core web UI can be published to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\core-app` and later if you have angular app, it can be published to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps\angular-app`. Both can access api1 easily, they just need correct configuration.